# Redis zrange by (score,member) tuple? - (not by index, not by score alone, not by member alone)

Tags: redis

I have a sorted set managed by redis, where member's score are dynamically updated (via zadd). Let's say current set is the following:

```
(10, A)
(20, B)
(20, C)
(30, D)
```

Note the items with duplicate scores for items B, and C.
Now say we want to fetch all items starting from a member C. And we also have a last known score for C (which is 20) that we obtained a while ago (e.g. as a result of a previous range command).

So we could do:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE myzset 20 +inf WITHSCORES
```

Since B has a same score with C, we will get (20,B) tuple first.
We can then find (20,C) lexicographically by scanning through the items with the same score. But here is the problem: what if the set is large and number of duplicate scores is large too? That's a lot of scanning... plus the network overhead for unneeded items.

Another solution would be get the rank of (20,C) using

```
ZRANK myzset C
```

which will give us 2 and we supply it to ZRANGE:

```
ZRANGE myzset 2 +inf WITHSCORES
```

But then the problem will arise if C was actually moved/rescored before we call ZRANK on it. For example if new C's score is 50, ZRANK will return last position in the set, thus we will only fetch (50,C) and miss all the remaining items.

I believe an appropriate way of doing this would be having a zrange by tuple. Something like

```
ZRANGE (20,C) +Inf
```

That would still give O(Log(N)) to search for (20,C) even if there are lots of duplicate scores of 20. 
That would also protect us from C moving to the bottom, as tuple range results would start from the next item (30,D), followed by (50,C)

For example, Cassandra, has a special syntax called multi-column restrictions where clustering keys could be compared as tuple: (score, member) >= (20, 'C').  In java it is also quite trivial to have a SortedSet of pairs.
But unfortunately Redis does not seem to expose this kind of access pattern.

So any workaround for the problem above?

Comment: If you want to traverse everything, I would say use `ZSCAN`.

Comment: I am talking about items within a single sorted set, ZSCAN is about traversing through multiple zsets owner keys as far as I know.

Comment: ZSCAN will iterate over the members of the ordered set. But the problem is that it will not do so in score order, but rather in random order, if you can live with it.

Comment: got it, well i need them sorted, so no ZSCAN is not an option.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how to you deal with duplicates? I.e. When you start iterating C's score is 10, and by the time you go to 80, C's score has increased to 100. Will you display it again?

Comment: There is a separate ephemeral set that keeps items already seen. The set has a session length expiration.

Comment: In similar manner, you could make a copy of the sorted set, like a snapshot, and iterate over that one? That's what I usually do for pagination.

Comment: interesting idea, will need to think about it some more, but i don't think it that it is going to scale for me, specifically making full replicas of sets in runtime.

Comment: Btw, the fastest way to copy a zset is to zunionstore it to the target.

Comment: In my use case each user has a separate zset computed by offline job as large as 10k items. I think doing a copy for each user is overkill, and most of the time users will refresh the top rather than scroll towards the bottom.